# python keyboard libary problem with writhing too many characters

Tags: python, keyboard, pywin32, pyautogui, python-keyboard

I am creating a automation that copies information of a cell that is focused and saves to a variable. While it does work, when I try to use the `keyboard` library or the `pyautogui` `write` function to type the variable on Notepad document, it stops working when there are more than 2 or 4 characters. When I attempt to write a larger amount, like with 9 characters, it starts delaying/lagging. I do not know what to do as I have tried many libraries and none seem to work. All I need to do with the program is to write the variable on a Notepad document.

There is a function that copies the focused cell on excel and saves it to a global variable. After, it descends one cell using `pyautogui`. This is the current code I have:

```py
import win32com.client as win32
import pyautogui
import global_variables


def copiar():
    try:
        excel = win32.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
    except:
        print("Excel not found.")
        return

    # Obter o nome da planilha ativa
    workbook_name = excel.ActiveWorkbook.Name

    # Se a planilha ativa não for a desejada, você pode abrir a planilha usando o seu caminho
    if workbook_name != 'CONEMB_ZLE.xlsx':
        # Exibe uma mensagem de aviso
        print("Excel not found, open.")
        return

    # Tornar o Excel visível
    excel.Visible = True

    # Selecionar a planilha ativa
    sheet = excel.ActiveSheet

    # Obter o valor da célula selecionada
    global_variables.valor_global = sheet.Application.Selection.Text

    # Imprimir o valor
    #print(global_variables.valor_global)

    # Pressionar a tecla de seta para baixo no teclado
    pyautogui.press('down')
```

This is the code that pastes the information on a Notepad document:

```py
while True:

    focus = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('CONEMB_ZLE - Excel')[0]
    focus.activate()
    copiar()
    item = global_variables.valor_global
    focus = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('transportadora - Bloco de notas')[0]
    focus.activate()
    print(item)

    keyboard.write(item)

    sleep(2)

    keyboard.press('enter')
```

It starts at the Excel tab and copies the data. It then goes to the Notepad tab and writes the variable containing the data on the Notepad document.

Comment: you probably don't need to call `pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle()` every iteration as I assume those don't change right?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, you don't need to use the `keyboard.write()` function, when you can just paste the variable in. Here, I decided to use `pyperclip`. When I tested the code, I noticed that `pyperclip.paste()` didn't work in different apps beside the terminal, so I came up with a backup solution. First, copy the item to the clipboard:

```
#import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy(item)
```

Then it's up to you how you want to paste it. In this case, you can use `keyboard` to press 'ctrl+v':

```
#import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy(item)
keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+v')
```

Alternatively, you may want to try to use `pyautogui.typewrite()` if that fails:

```
pyautogui.typewrite(item)
```

I think that the copy and paste method is most efficient however, and will probably fix the lag.

Comment: tnx its really helped me